# mediaelement.js setSrc method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediaelement.js

I try using mediaelement.js..

```
var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player',{
 startVolume:0.5,
 alwaysShowControls:true
});
```

it's nice working when "src" is static. but with dynamic src

```
player.setSrc('link_to_audio');
```

browser returns error - **TypeError: Object # has no method 'setSrc'**

browsers - Chromium 23.0.1300.0 (170000) and FF 19.0.2

Comment: omg.. it's work)

    player.player.setSrc('link_to_audio');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement/blob/master/docs/usage.md#initialize) says that you should initialize it like this :

```
var player = new MediaElementPlayer('player',{
```

rather than like this

```
var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player',{
```

or using jQuery :

```
$('#player").mediaelementplayer({
```